# Парсинг элементов генерируемые JS скриптом

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Здравствуйте,хочу спарсить имена из секции following и followers на coub.com,чтобы потом сравнить разницу между этими секциями,но есть одно недоразумение.Эти самые элементы генерируются JS скриптом и BeautifulSoup их не видит. На данный момент мне приходится делать эти [действия](https://vimeo.com/225457428). Неужели тут поможет только Selenium ? Или может есть библиотеки получше ? Главное мне понять как парсить сайты с JS.

Comment: Чтобы парсить js, этот js должен кто-то исполнять. И тут рулят разного вида браузеры и все что ими управляет. Есть еще вот это https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash, а именно https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, но я не изучал что оно такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам куб выдаст все в машиночитаемом виде, если его попросить. Заходите на страничку которую хотите парсить и откройте вэб инспектор. Переходите на вкладку network и смотрите что делает яваскрипт при нажатии кнопки followers.

Первый попавшийся автор на кубе:

http://coub.com/api/v2/action_subjects_data/followers_list?id=2878340&page=1

```
{"page":1,"total_pages":2,"channels":[{"id":119783,"permalink":"70d0eddb3c423142e4b595123c080fa7","title":"Infernozzz","description":null,"followers_count":5,"following_count":25,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b118/p/channel/cw_avatar/d567af7d6df/5b9d5057a2615d0855972/%{version}_1474486986_CameraZOOM-20121218013951615.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":157999,"permalink":"8ecc7a0bffe6f54af3b019da1ca9eb31","title":"Ruos","description":null,"followers_count":16,"following_count":25,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b20/p/channel/cw_avatar/c3921d7a250/2fa57270b661f1027a68d/%{version}_1474489647_14119785981190.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":202858,"permalink":"276fb9f94d5a3b1a3d7eb387565b87c4","title":"Peter Sazonov","description":null,"followers_count":18,"following_count":5,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b85/p/channel/cw_avatar/32a083f196a/fb2862a4b2dcfd57f69d9/%{version}_1474492544_jkde5j_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":300900,"permalink":"egorovdmitry","title":"egorovdmitry","description":null,"followers_count":33,"following_count":29,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s2.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b119/p/channel/cw_avatar/7daeb064a1e/0947c5a4a2bff2ef28ac0/%{version}_1474497784_1p3ty45_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":323171,"permalink":"kalianches","title":"Коля Котельник","description":null,"followers_count":4,"following_count":12,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s3.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b20/p/channel/cw_avatar/589109f4a82/7dea01ea9e07463e63dc0/%{version}_1474499186_xt85fl_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":351148,"permalink":"indigo-artist","title":"indigo_artist","description":"for your sick brain from this sick world","followers_count":480,"following_count":1804,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b188/p/channel/cw_avatar/189b6b8bb5e/6cfeb21c66272e8fb01da/%{version}_1496166969_1169692_718617788274875_1784984380_a.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":726106,"permalink":"shadowodi1397424888","title":"Димон Орехов","description":null,"followers_count":97,"following_count":672,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b20/p/channel/cw_avatar/941ed1a4be4/34ef30027bc2b66e984a5/%{version}_1474526887_mqcl8s_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":909289,"permalink":"bonuscrystals","title":"BonusCrystals ","description":"trick or treat smell my feet\r\ngive me something good to eat","followers_count":10435,"following_count":565,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b105/p/channel/cw_avatar/2d907512bcd/d9eb94a88f551e84c57b1/%{version}_1474549085_CrystalBonus.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1079187,"permalink":"nikaarevadze","title":"ნიკა არევაძე","description":null,"followers_count":46,"following_count":136,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b132/p/channel/cw_avatar/1f4b399d5bc/8518afb7060894c9094da/%{version}_1474685640_1rmmn4_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1091587,"permalink":"223d842a9ad1eb8e1d4dc00ef0c832bb","title":"Vladimir Simonov","description":null,"followers_count":24,"following_count":41,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b129/p/channel/cw_avatar/7235ceab1dc/f6e2b4a6da8412eb3bed7/%{version}_1474648234_15uuzqk_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1163679,"permalink":"maksim.makin","title":"Maxim Makin","description":null,"followers_count":40,"following_count":109,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b85/p/channel/cw_avatar/3d6f34feae2/fe659ce151675d0984ca2/%{version}_1474594116_x81u0g_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1170065,"permalink":"vhodikin","title":"Volodymir Hodykin","description":null,"followers_count":49,"following_count":191,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s2.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b14/p/channel/cw_avatar/1d8ffc735f5/66f29aa2a71c5f3d561c6/%{version}_1474666965_1ic2j6_att-url-download.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1299574,"permalink":"inlight.lightbringer","title":"InLight LightBringer","description":null,"followers_count":6,"following_count":94,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s3.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b85/p/channel/cw_avatar/985a764ef44/e0d3a43add0c4f5baf03b/%{version}_1474597060_10547930.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1300419,"permalink":"youhhou2","title":"Youhhou","description":null,"followers_count":14,"following_count":14,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b107/p/channel/cw_avatar/8fbbb035c85/927ee4f61eefbd1da7857/%{version}_1474566990_Untitled-1.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1561206,"permalink":"dfaa7760173dfb8af7cfe671d468f412","title":"alex-racer","description":null,"followers_count":8,"following_count":23,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b112/p/channel/cw_avatar/d582b4b0538/ba169d9a45155cae99482/%{version}_1474645591_722604414526135.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1563657,"permalink":"2ddbe4b0cd61ccda5b04fdce2c400087","title":"WonderBoy","description":null,"followers_count":18,"following_count":21,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b20/p/channel/cw_avatar/b6fe3d9e105/f585f8ba6b54373be3f2c/%{version}_1474541024_87889945.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1643964,"permalink":"stam55555","title":"Nightbreeze","description":null,"followers_count":35,"following_count":226,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b188/p/channel/cw_avatar/953d4f06ff9/d7f390594c0538ce82b5a/%{version}_1499658533_cropped.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":1937104,"permalink":"alexander.moiseev","title":"Alexander Moiseev","description":null,"followers_count":0,"following_count":4,"avatar_versions":{}},{"id":2054458,"permalink":"bfcc857c5788beb0f9a5058e8818ea20","title":"Martin","description":null,"followers_count":193,"following_count":2303,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b131/p/channel/cw_avatar/e09a4417301/8a99d85dd26e70aa565b9/%{version}_1489320989_14295499_952854308171350_7987654119810662400_n.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2323712,"permalink":"d80bc72e97f202c4634bff6d05906aff","title":"SuleymanOzdogan","description":null,"followers_count":38,"following_count":706,"avatar_versions":{}},{"id":2433850,"permalink":"336fc36b9ae747dfaef5d172518bf2b1","title":"Alivrok","description":"Sense Seeker -- Atmospheric coubs -- \r\n -- To comment it's possible there ☞ →","followers_count":1626,"following_count":779,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b89/p/channel/cw_avatar/44a46934c43/4190d582785791964b81f/%{version}_1474620680_Moonwatch.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2450631,"permalink":"kenwayzzz","title":"Alternative","description":"freestyle","followers_count":25,"following_count":15,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b99/p/channel/cw_avatar/c1756787be3/0f43319871eec5b4df85a/%{version}_1476813031_che_guevara-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2464065,"permalink":"bc4f2f4a954db57546082a5a8f4cfa96","title":"MariaBrum","description":null,"followers_count":2,"following_count":14,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b132/p/channel/cw_avatar/f47ed252f0a/33d60e30224732383084d/%{version}_1474661795_3ywvlm_1072116796144190.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2489229,"permalink":"120d6ef838aec4e40066144c22bd9608","title":"Mari krikheli","description":null,"followers_count":64,"following_count":161,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b24/p/channel/cw_avatar/0732cdc933c/3791a00b9598eb33a3fe3/%{version}_1491860138_cropped.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2491366,"permalink":"3ff0cd6f9208b34e795e4185c6869aa8","title":"Monsieur Tengo","description":null,"followers_count":25,"following_count":85,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b164/p/channel/cw_avatar/187d09e993d/02e01d434b887cd17e735/%{version}_1482088035_filename.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2494515,"permalink":"8f4ff7f9ba2738b1b3ce66b58385d84f","title":"valfar","description":null,"followers_count":23,"following_count":306,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b20/p/channel/cw_avatar/79965918f3d/311dfc1f36254c94f90ab/%{version}_1474614824_1hdox6d_498765123649451.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2510566,"permalink":"5111ddda447138624d24c751d90192ce","title":"ikadoriano","description":null,"followers_count":9,"following_count":20,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b85/p/channel/cw_avatar/76152dcbc6f/d018146b49ae165809cab/%{version}_1474601813_12496211_1080130375351596_1261989438954695420_o.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2574793,"permalink":"f1cd6ac47cc54933cba90003e616684c","title":"Arkady  Raevsky","description":null,"followers_count":0,"following_count":6,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b85/p/channel/cw_avatar/89012fa75ed/9f56e1f51f1331eac8d76/%{version}_1474687484_p5w80g_563376833835598.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2596011,"permalink":"e1122a91e18ce27a6bf21e7c6bc47d44","title":"Motherfuckah' Jones","description":null,"followers_count":325,"following_count":331,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b182/p/channel/cw_avatar/5fc92c7502e/7add366cef7c1908c4a54/%{version}_1499844793_19732313_1776718082346200_1777154974083542103_n.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2715266,"permalink":"g-joaquin","title":"Golda","description":null,"followers_count":71,"following_count":33,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s3.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b116/p/channel/cw_avatar/146936e4ad6/b12543f25f90e0f959c1a/%{version}_1474640642_g-joaquin.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2716699,"permalink":"omar-ouimette","title":"Ouimette","description":null,"followers_count":78,"following_count":29,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b124/p/channel/cw_avatar/2615946825e/6e07f39eba81ca66a9766/%{version}_1474562985_omar-ouimette.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":2758126,"permalink":"7de478b14339851551b01064917c889c","title":"Vitaly  Zakharov","description":null,"followers_count":0,"following_count":4,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b1/p/channel/cw_avatar/d1bdbf26242/8dc05db18977235e78bc1/%{version}_1469517949_1vf98ed_491233914334576.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3122990,"permalink":"6e2655d9e6558d8326c737afa9ad07f1","title":"JeffSFlex1","description":null,"followers_count":1,"following_count":20,"avatar_versions":{}},{"id":3127355,"permalink":"376622c8a7ad518ab580be3a33019985","title":"__stveg__","description":null,"followers_count":156,"following_count":1643,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b176/p/channel/cw_avatar/ba1c7ef6de3/64319e924c2222437dc57/%{version}_1497423600_cropped.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3204749,"permalink":"3aad41935d2fe80e8fd2edc6b0a06d04","title":"Unfeverish","description":"I love the way you take up space.","followers_count":5,"following_count":84,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s2.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b140/p/channel/cw_avatar/6fab28bafde/37404cb4b3f735e6d14e1/%{version}_1482534408_filename.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3422619,"permalink":"0a2e8e290e56db54dc3f616be524aac0","title":"Антон Шаров","description":null,"followers_count":4,"following_count":26,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b26/p/channel/cw_avatar/fcdd8125fc1/bb703dd7c5b25d26c71db/%{version}_1486212295_w7ygjk_18663937.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3426120,"permalink":"9c5deead3a9b522d0b0e7aeaafac2b7f","title":"Dariel Calluna","description":null,"followers_count":29,"following_count":298,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b90/p/channel/cw_avatar/168ba378df2/8cd0b35264c5e015c143d/%{version}_1487706084_filename.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3426426,"permalink":"2df93d24769405b8aab607fb052b94ed","title":"Валентин Шерстюк","description":null,"followers_count":1,"following_count":5,"avatar_versions":{}},{"id":3478396,"permalink":"943b882d499f90b2593c9c50e46783fc","title":"Mariami","description":null,"followers_count":3,"following_count":19,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b80/p/channel/cw_avatar/f78c55526b0/4d38f9bf753185cefa11b/%{version}_1489393629_f39yqw_1886236521660639.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3484021,"permalink":"dying.light.-.so.fun","title":"So Fun&Crazy","description":"Приколы и чики, в основном репосты","followers_count":194,"following_count":2429,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s3.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b115/p/channel/cw_avatar/a88ba9c328d/fc04969dddab844c303ca/%{version}_1489654274_1476431751_lico-anglo-saksonskoy-nacionalnosti.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3509130,"permalink":"3e8d7667cb4a036fb1e705a3cc6b8c13","title":"madnezz","description":null,"followers_count":4,"following_count":33,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b125/p/channel/cw_avatar/1b37a503cbc/e6a198f1f17060b9865dc/%{version}_1491066792_cropped.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3529401,"permalink":"649f2e96695798ae0acda4c0a34f8709","title":"xv","description":"kik- xmisfitxtoysx","followers_count":10,"following_count":58,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s4.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b174/p/channel/cw_avatar/10eb1bb9218/105057bef5744496d5e49/%{version}_1499850863_cropped.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3560811,"permalink":"beautiful.world","title":"World","description":null,"followers_count":345,"following_count":4714,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b97/p/channel/cw_avatar/86a627f8b2e/c5e44f723632b78327af2/%{version}_1493812276_ut5zwKNIVxI.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3561156,"permalink":"1f7bf4b8cc66d1197711986c0e0bf94b","title":"enotikyskryt","description":null,"followers_count":9,"following_count":79,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s1.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b88/p/channel/cw_avatar/6a7ae444853/71ee44fddf29e8496dba2/%{version}_1493829642_3xu4dv_118330263707649641317.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3563519,"permalink":"8976d069d81d5b1e45f5912b51a001b1","title":"wowabest","description":null,"followers_count":1,"following_count":10,"avatar_versions":{}},{"id":3569695,"permalink":"b285ff85d7269c18a6afd8e02256c983","title":"Nina","description":null,"followers_count":9,"following_count":67,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s3.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b77/p/channel/cw_avatar/7314672f56e/9553b42038936a6f27690/%{version}_1494520102_filename.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3583334,"permalink":"afa573d5868498aafa47a568b9a39dce","title":"StayingCruissin","description":"I like to edit","followers_count":3,"following_count":31,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b82/p/channel/cw_avatar/f8abc82fa04/b728ab340484d174e7a36/%{version}_1494971124_filename.jpeg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3590249,"permalink":"3d2b7f31618fa0aa93d25e1268a01ef7","title":"nata","description":null,"followers_count":2,"following_count":35,"avatar_versions":{"template":"http://s3.storage.akamai.coub.com/get/b180/p/channel/cw_avatar/cc5ba82672c/b8646a453481efc045c5a/%{version}_1501410119_19113796_1932071560342208_2143544418904620060_n.jpg","versions":["medium","medium_2x","profile_pic","profile_pic_new","profile_pic_new_2x","tiny","tiny_2x","small","small_2x","ios_large","ios_small"]}},{"id":3614382,"permalink":"69537eefd827a4dcef497c4b31bdf418","title":"Вадим Виноградов","description":null,"followers_count":0,"following_count":13,"avatar_versions":{}},{"id":3628972,"permalink":"12de28e0e00b764ff5f93c3bf33dcbc9","title":"Olega","description":null,"followers_count":0,"following_count":15,"avatar_versions":{}}]}
```

ответ загружаете в json.loads() и работаете со словарем. Суп не нужен на этом сайте.

"total_pages":2 - в самом начале ответа есть количество страничек

Comment: +1 полезно на вкладку Network посмотреть и если есть у сайта API лучше его использовать вместо web scraping. Учитывая широту вопроса, стоит упомянуть как получить содержимое, генерируемое в JavaScript, если сайт не предоставляет API. Если [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960288/4279) не подходит, то можно использовать [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) или другие [headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

Comment: selenium это другая опера. можете написать отдельный ответ по этому поводу

Comment: Автор явно упомянул selenium в вопросе, поэтому я и написал "если selenium не подходит".  Для сайта в вопросе ваш ответ подходит, но для будущих читателей, которые могут захотеть и с других сайтов информацию собирать, стоит упомянуть варианты с headless browser, что я и сделал. На ответ это не тянет — мой комментарий это дополнение к вашему ответу.

Comment: ничего не надо крутить колесиком. есть же page=1 и перебирай эту циферку дальше

Comment: "page":1,"total_pages":2 в самом начале ответа количество страничек